# Я не могу понять, почему так происходит

Tags: python, windows, list, pycharm

```
abc = ['a', 'b', 'c']
c = abc
print(type(abc))
print(type(c))
for i in c:
    if i == 'a' or i == 'b' or i == 'c':
        c.remove(i)
        i += 'y'
        c.append(i)
print(c)
```

Я не могу понять почему при выводе выводит ['b', 'ay', 'cy'], а не ['ay', 'cy', 'by']
И у 'c' и у 'abc' тип list, но вывод расходится с результатом.
Зато когда я пишу, что 'c' именно list(), то все отлично работает:

```
abc = ['a', 'b', 'c']
c = abc
print(type(abc))
print(type(c))
for i in list(c):
    if i == 'a' or i == 'b' or i == 'c':
        c.remove(i)
        i += 'y'
        c.append(i)
print(c)
```

Объясните пожалуйста как это работает.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Программа выполняется не так, как Вы хотите, потому что переменная i сначала удаляется, потом к ней прибавляется 'y' и она добавляется в **конец** списка. Чтобы код выполнялся правильно необходимо сделать так:

```
abc = ['a', 'b', 'c']
c = abc
print(type(abc))
print(type(c))
for i in range(len(c)):
    if c[i] == 'a' or c[i] == 'b' or c[i] == 'c':
        c[i] = c[i] + 'y'
print(c)
```

Теперь всё происходит так, как задумано.
Во втором случае вы используете не сам список, а его копию, поэтому изменения происходящие в списке c, не отражаются в ней.

P S Иногда необходимо использовать [визуализатор](https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit). Я, например, понял, что идёт не так только после работы с ним.

Answer (score 2):

потому что сколько раз говорили - НЕ МЕНЯЙТЕ СПИСОК (УДАЛЯТЬ/ДОБАВЛЯТЬ элементы) КОГДА ДВИГАЕТЕСЬ ПО НЕМУ

вы ломаете логику работы `for`

когда же вы делаете

```
for i in list(c):
```

то ползаете по одному объекту (`list(c)`) - копии списка `c`, а меняете другой объект - сам список `c`

В первом примере происходит примерно следующее:

позиция в списке `c` - `pos = 0`, значение - `a`

удаляете этот элемент списка и у вас получается список `['b', 'c']`

дальше добавляете к списку элемент `ay` и у вас получается список `['b', 'c', 'ay']`

дальше переходите к следующему элементу в списке `c` - `pos = 1`, значение... `c`, потому что после удаления первого элемента списка все сдвинулось

в итоге удаляете элемент списка `c` и добавляете `cy`, получился список `['b', 'ay', 'cy']`

цикл завершился, поскольку вы достигли конец первоначального списка

Answer (score 1):

А вы добавьте отладочную печать:

```
...
for i in c:
    print(i, c)
    ...
```

Вывод:

```
a ['a', 'b', 'c']
c ['b', 'c', 'ay']
cy ['b', 'ay', 'cy']
```

Видите? Список меняется на ходу, при этом у него перебираются элементы просто по номеру. Поэтому на второй итерации элемент `b` просто не перебирается - после `remove` он стал первым. Зато на третьей итерации в `i` будет `cy`, потому что он в этот момент на третьем месте.

Чинится это как обычно - итерацией по копии списка, вы делаете копию через `list`, но лучше делать копию явным образом:

```
for i in c.copy():
```

Вывод отладочной печати в этом случае:

```
a ['a', 'b', 'c']
b ['b', 'c', 'ay']
c ['c', 'ay', 'by']
```

Теперь всё как задумано.